# Oficejs Show/Hide context menu dynamically

Tags: javascript, office-js

I am using officejs to create a word add-in using angular framework. I've added context menu in manifest file. Now,I want to show the context menu only when there is text selected in document else hide the menu.
Is it possible to show/hide context menu dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at this time with Office.js add-ins. But it is a good idea. Please suggest it at [Office developer suggestion box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).